# How filter/sort images/blocks in jquery?

Tags: jquery, sorting, filtering

We have 100+ images on page. Each image has 3 parameters:

- Year (2007|2008|2009)
- Color (red|yellow|blue)
- Type (portrait|panoram)

How do I sort images on page with this parameters (i want to see blue+panorams+2007) without page reloading - just selecting the right images?

**P.S.** I don't know how to sign parameters, in class i guses like class="2009 yellow blue portrait" without using external files

Comment: please 1) show your markup, and 2) define "selecting"

Comment: More importantly, please define how the parameters are assigned.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume the following markup... you can adapt it to your own:

```
<div id="images">
  <div>
    <img src="..." />
    <em>Year: </em><span class="year">2007</span>
    <em>Color: </em><span class="color">red</span>
    <em>Type: </em><span class="type">portrait</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="..." />
    <em>Year: </em><span class="year">2008</span>
    <em>Color: </em><span class="color">yellow</span>
    <em>Type: </em><span class="type">panoram</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then this is the jQuery you'll need:

```
function sortBy(field) {
    var container = $('#images');
    // get a real array of the image divs
    var imgDivList = container.children().get();
    // Put them into the correct order based on the chosen field
    imgDivList.sort(function (a, b) {
        var aText = $(a).children('.' + field).text();
        var bText = $(b).children('.' + field).text();
        if (aText < bText) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (aText > bText) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (aText == bText) {
            return 0;
        }
    });
    // Append them back to the original container
    container.append(imgDivList);
}
```

For filtering, do this:

```
function filter(field, value) {
    var imgDivList = $('#images').children();
    imgDivList.each(function (index, element) {
        if ($(element).children('.' + field).text() == value) {
            $(element).show();
        } else {
            $(element).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the general idea. You need to create a true array of the images, then sort them using JavaScript `array.sort` and a custom function. Once that's done, you can `append` them right back to the DOM and they'll rearrange themselves.

```
arrImages = $('img').get(); // need a true array
arrImages.sort(function(a,b) {
    // write your own sort function here using your parameters
    // return a negative number to sort a before b, positive to sort b before a
});
$.each(arrImages, function(i,el) {
    $('#container').append(el);
});
```